# JSON schema for unknown properties that are objects with date-time property names

Tags: jsonschema

Here's some sample data I'm trying to build a schema for:

```
{
    "measurement data": {
        "interval data": {
            "2022-09-14T16:00:00+0:00": {
                "duration": 300,
                "Leq": 65.2
            },
            "2022-09-14T16:05:00+0:00": {
                "duration": 300,
                "Leq": 64.3
            },
            "2022-09-14T16:10:00+0:00": {
                "duration": 300,
                "Leq": 61.1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The properties of interval data are objects with property names that are ISO 8601 formatted date-time strings. What's the best way to implement this?

I think I could use `patternProperties` with a regex to match an ISO 8601 string. I took a stab at this below (there's an escaping issue I'm stuck on, so it's broken).

There's already a format definition called ['date-time' in the JSON schema](https://opis.io/json-schema/2.x/formats.html#date-time) which would be handy to use but I don't see how this can be used in `patternProperties`.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/schema",
  "$id": "http://example.com/example.json",
  "type": "object",
  "default": {},
  "title": "Root Schema",
  "required": [
    "measurement data"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "measurement data": {
      "type": "object",
      "default": {},
      "title": "The measurement data Schema",
      "required": [
        "interval data"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "interval data": {
          "type": "object",
          "default": {},
          "title": "The interval data Schema",
          "patternProperties": {
            "^([\\+-]?\\d{4}(?!\\d{2}\\b))((-?)((0[1-9]|1[0-2])(\\3([12]\\d|0[1-9]|3[01]))?|W([0-4]\\d|5[0-2])(-?[1-7])?|(00[1-9]|0[1-9]\\d|[12]\\d{2}|3([0-5]\\d|6[1-6])))([T\\s]((([01]\\d|2[0-3])((:?)[0-5]\\d)?|24\\:?00)([\\.,]\\d+(?!:))?)?(\\17[0-5]\\d([\\.,]\\d+)?)?([zZ]|([\\+-])([01]\\d|2[0-3]):?([0-5]\\d)?)?)?)?$": {
              "type": "object",
              "default": {},
              "title": "The timestamp Schema",
              "required": [
                "duration",
                "Leq"
              ],
              "properties": {
                "duration": {
                  "type": "integer",
                  "default": 0,
                  "title": "The duration Schema",
                  "examples": [
                    300
                  ]
                },
                "Leq": {
                  "type": "number",
                  "default": 0,
                  "title": "The Leq Schema",
                  "examples": [
                    65.2
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a schema for a property name with (drum roll) the `propertyNames` keyword:

```
{
  "propertyNames": { "format": "date-time" },
  "additionalProperties": {
    ... schema for the property values here ...
  }
}
```

see https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/object.html#property-names

Comment: I suppose it's up to the implementation of the validator, but I've tried multiple and none of them are catching invalid date-time formats with this approach.  Pattern criteria works however.

Comment: You need to check the documentation for the validator you are using to see how to turn on format validation, as the specification says it must be off by default.

Answer (score -2):

Regular expressions start in `/` and end in `/`. So maybe instead of:
`"^([\\+-]?\\d{4}(?!\\d{2}\\b))((-?)((0[1-9]|1[0-2])(\\3([12]\\d|0[1-9]|3[01]))?|W([0-4]\\d|5[0-2])(-?[1-7])?|(00[1-9]|0[1-9]\\d|[12]\\d{2}|3([0-5]\\d|6[1-6])))([T\\s]((([01]\\d|2[0-3])((:?)[0-5]\\d)?|24\\:?00)([\\.,]\\d+(?!:))?)?(\\17[0-5]\\d([\\.,]\\d+)?)?([zZ]|([\\+-])([01]\\d|2[0-3]):?([0-5]\\d)?)?)?)?$"`
try:
`"/^([\\+-]?\\d{4}(?!\\d{2}\\b))((-?)((0[1-9]|1[0-2])(\\3([12]\\d|0[1-9]|3[01]))?|W([0-4]\\d|5[0-2])(-?[1-7])?|(00[1-9]|0[1-9]\\d|[12]\\d{2}|3([0-5]\\d|6[1-6])))([T\\s]((([01]\\d|2[0-3])((:?)[0-5]\\d)?|24\\:?00)([\\.,]\\d+(?!:))?)?(\\17[0-5]\\d([\\.,]\\d+)?)?([zZ]|([\\+-])([01]\\d|2[0-3]):?([0-5]\\d)?)?)?)?$/"`.

Comment: This won't work. In jsonschema, die regexs are provided without the slashes. However, since they're are JSON strings, backslashes need to be double escaped: once for usage in the JSON string and a second time for usage in the regex